# Delete words in list that don't meet condition

Tags: python, list

I have a list of words in Python:

```
['apple', 'ball', 'app']
```

I want to delete all words that don't start with `'app'`.

How do I produce the list `['apple', 'app']`?

I know to use `startswith`, but I'm not sure what the list comprehension would look like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[word for word in my_list if word.startswith('app')]` should do it

Comment: For anyone who's unfamiliar, this is called list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `re.search` here to retain only terms beginning with `app`:

```
list_in = ['apple', 'ball', 'app']
list_out = [ x for x in list_in if re.search(r'^app', x)]
print(list_out)
```

This prints:

```
['apple', 'app']
```